# Environment configuration in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, api, configuration

Using AngularjS for a simple dashboard consuming a API from a different server.

To assign the APIURL in angularJS to a certain value, i currently use app.constant() in app.js file.

But this is not the best methods because, this URL changes for staging, development, testing and production.

So everytime the code is deployed i need to change the APIURL value.

And i cannot use process.env.NODE_ENV becasuse this can be used only for server side/express framework.

Is there a way i can configure all different API URL's for different environments and dont have to change the variable value during deployment to different environment servers.

Comment: I would say this is subject to personal preference. For bigger projects, i tend to create a kind of `is_debug` variable, so you have only one thing to change and the rest follows. However, in smaller projects, i could consider that it's probably better to have my debug URL still in the code, and edit manually. Another option is to have a kind of app "compiler" that produces one clean version or the other..

Answer (score 0):

We pass in an environment parameter in the URL.  I don't know if that is a common best practice or not, it's just what we use.

I did find a post that goes into more detail for this topic: [How to configure Angularjs using Environment Variables](https://www.jvandemo.com/how-to-configure-your-angularjs-application-using-environment-variables/).  He uses a .js file that gets overwritten when you change the environment, but it's still using an environment variable.

Comment: I am currently using this method. But want to find if there are better ways to do.